# Unable to access a string from the json object even by using angular.fromJson()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

```
   {
    "data": {
        "weather": [{
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }],
        "id": 1271714,
        "name": "Gandhi Nagar",
        "cod": 200
    },
    "status": 200,
    "config": {
        "method": "GET",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "url": "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=13.0414146&lon=80.2599991&appid=016040457f30e1967b4025f18e225136",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        }
    },
    "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Unable to access the `data.name` string. The method I use is as follows. The below mentioned method returns an error. I am new to AngularJS, please do help me if I am making any mistake.

```
var city = angular.fromJson(result.data.name);
```

Comment: Could you show your `$http` call ?

Comment: It works fine(Assuming your JSON is being assigned properly)? [Plunkr Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/gOAcsOu0tJXxmGR2xkzL?p=preview)

Comment: Have you tried result.name directly?

Comment: It works for all other data like result.data.cod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
result = angular.fromJson(result);
var city = result.data.name;
```

Comment: it worked..!! But can you tell me why my method didn't work..??

Comment: From what I understand angular.fromJson() requires a JSON input. I assumed that ```result``` is the JSON object you got. You would need to convert the whole JSON object first and extract the object property you need, instead of extracting the property first and converting only that part to string. Anyone please correct me if I'm wrong. 
What I did not understand is why it required fromJson conversion in the first place: simply ```var city = result.data.name;``` usually just works for me.

Comment: @yclee0210: Your description is correct. Well, the data that has been provided in the question is not really a JSON string. In fact it's a simple object and accessing properties directly should not raise an error. The error may have been caused because he tried to parse a simple string (`result.data.name`). Parsing a number on the other hand works just fine (`result.data.cod`). A real JSON string would have the outer `{}` placed inside another pair of `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `angular.fromJson`needs an valid json string and `result.data.name` is not a vaild json string. After deserializeing this string into JSON object you are able to get your value.

```
var city = angular.fromJson(result).data.name;
```